# Understanding python3 docs example code

Tags: python

Why doesn't the very first iteration go to the first print statement. After all, isn't 2%2==0?

```
>>> for n in range(2, 10):
...     for x in range(2, n):
...         if n % x == 0:
...             print(n, 'equals', x, '*', n//x)
...             break
...     else:
...         # loop fell through without finding a factor
...         print(n, 'is a prime number')
...
2 is a prime number
3 is a prime number
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first time through the loop, `n = 2` so `x` is in `range(2, 2)` which is an empty list.  Iterating over an empty list doesn't go into the inner loop but does executes the `else` clause.

Comment: Thanks! I thought that range would have a single element: [2].

Answer (score 0):

2 is not in `range(2, 2)`.  The upper bound of `range` is exclusive, so it stops before reaching it.